# How to stop textview field from flashing when clicked

Tags: java, android

I'm creating a timer application for my android.  It counts down from a specified time (i.e. 8 minutes) to 0.

I have coded it that when the app starts it shows the specified time.  When you click on the `TextView` displaying the time it starts the count down updating the `TextView` at the `onTick()` event.  When you click on the `TextView` again it will stop the countdown and save the remaining milliseconds to resume when the `TextView` is clicked the next time (essentially pausing the clock).

Everything works as expected.  However, when the `TextView` is clicked it disappears until the click is released.  If I hold the click down for 3 seconds then the `TextView` totally disappears while it is being held and reappears as soon as it is released.

How can I stop this behavior to continue to show the value of the `TextView` the whole time?

EDIT:

```
    tvPeriod.setOnLongClickListener( new View.OnLongClickListener() {           
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            valPeriod = 1;
            tvPeriod.setText( tvPeriodPrefix + "1" );

            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Put some code here of what you are doing.

Comment: @AliImran - I have added the code as requested.  No matter what I seem to do when you click on the element it disappears and then reappears when I let go.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably do something like set the background to a color, or even transparent. Actually on the lower level, a Button is descended from a TextView, so that may explain why it can act like a Button.

Comment: The background of what?  The textview is completely disappearing when I click on the textview.  Once I let go of the click it then reappears.  So the background of what?  Is there a different background set for when something is getting clicked?

Answer (score 0):

Try with this sample code.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    TextView tv;
    CountDownTimer countDownTimer;
    boolean isRunning = false;
    long remainingTime = 90000;
    long elapsedTime = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);
        tv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (isRunning) {
                    isRunning = false;
                    countDownTimer.cancel();
                    remainingTime = elapsedTime;
                } else {
                    countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(remainingTime, 1000) {

                        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                            elapsedTime = millisUntilFinished;
                            tv.setText("seconds remaining: "
                                    + millisUntilFinished / 1000);

                        }

                        public void onFinish() {
                            tv.setText("done!");
                        }
                    }.start();
                    isRunning = true;
                }

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```